# Apache JMeter not getting response

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I'm testing several functions and in some I'm having problems increasing the number of requests. For example, I was testing the factors function with 32 requests in 30 seconds and I had no problem, but when increasing to 64 requests I had the following problem:

[open requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8M2y.png)

Requests open normally

[completed requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAfrk.png)

but after they finish their execution i don't get any response in jmeter. It seems that the connection was lost and it is waiting for the timeout .

I'm testing a weak VM, only 1 vCPU and 2Gb.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler by default it will wait for response "forever" (unless the [TCP timeout](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20735/tcp-timeout-how-long-does-it-last) is set somewhere in underlying JDK or [OS](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-increasing-or-decreasing-tcp-sockets-timeouts.html))

So if your application gets overloaded and fails to respond JMeter will wait for the response infinitely, in order to avoid the situation with "hanging" test consider setting reasonable connect and response timeouts, the setting live under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) if you have more than one HTTP Request sampler in your Test Plan)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm already using timeout, the problem is that the VM finishes executing but the answer is not arriving in the jmeter